# Ubuntu 19.10 Graphic issue with vmware workstation installed

Tags: intel-graphics, 19.10, vmware-workstation

Recently i had upgraded to 18.04 LTS to 19.10 and installed Vmware Workstation 15 pro.

After install VMware workstation pro 15 and reboot got Unbuntu freezing boot screen (Purple and keep on loading) where i had manages to edit grub to "nomodeset" and loaded the OS but after faced tearing screen

after a lot troubleshooting i have found Graphic driver was change what i have noticed

OpenGL Vendor string was change as below after installing vmware workstation 15 pro

OpenGL vendor string: Vmware Inc

and before installing vmware workstation 15 pro it as below

OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center

Just now i have uninstalled vmware workstation 15 pro and issued is fixed no more freezing boot screen and tearing screen.

Do any one in the community face same issue ? or is the driver problem ?